# find replace import file values in spss-modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

I'm using Modeler 18.0 and I'm new to the tool.

I inherited 30 stream files. Each stream starts with 30 excel source nodes with file names like \.xlsx (e.g. c:\source\regl_sales_01_WI_2017Q3.xlsx). I need to update all 900 nodes for the 2017Q4 versions of the source files.

Can I do this with some type of script where I can find and replace? Would this be a stand alone script? Seems like I could use something like node.setPropertyValue("full_filename", "c:\source\regl_sales_01_WI_2017Q3.xlsx") If I can only identify the script and node.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved using standalone scripting and the `stream.findAll()`-functionality.

You could do something like this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

session = modeler.script.session()
tasks = session.getTaskRunner()
mypath = 'C:\\yourpath'
streams = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if (isfile(join(mypath, f)) and f.endswith(".str"))]
for streamFile in streams:
    print(stream.getName()+" is getting processed.")
    stream = tasks.openStreamFromFile(demosDir + streamFile, True)
    inputNodes = stream.findAll("excelimport", None)
    for in in inputNodes:
        ff = in.getPropertyValue("full_filename")
        ff.replace("2017Q3.xlsx", "2017Q4.xlsx")
        in.setPropertyValue("full_filename", ff)
    print(stream.getName()+" is processed.")
    stream.close()
```

I did not test this, but it shouldn't need a lot of tweaking to work.